# Python instructions outside Try: Except:

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a single line inside a Try/Except block, but another line outside this block is being executed when there is an exception. I'm on my phone so I'll just enter a few lines

```
try:
    total=total+int(number)
except:
    print('Bad input')
count = count + 1
```

When I enter a number, the count gets incremented as expected. If a character is entered, the exception is caught, but the count still gets incremented. I thought only the lines within the try/except block were repeated if there was an exception.

Comment: Try-except statements don't automatically repeat anything. If you have a `while` loop wrapped around this or something, your `while` loop is going to repeat the whole loop body.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `else` clause of the `try/except` statement if you only want to increment `count` if an exception was *not* raised. [From the documentation section *8.3 Handling Exceptions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> The try ... except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

```
try:
    total += int(number)
except ValueError:
    print('Bad input')
else:
    count += 1
```

As you can see from above, I changed your bare except statement to catch a specific exception type `ValueError`, since that's will `int` will raise if it can't convert it's argument to an `int`. If you want to catch a different exception, change `ValueError`, but don't use a bare `except` clause, as it can mask important exceptions.

Also as said in the comments, a `try/except` statement *does not* execute it's body multiple times. You need a loop if you want that behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I mistakenly thought the try/except worked like a loop on its own. Rookie mistake. This was included in a while loop, but I did not want to type it on my phone. I did not know about the Else option, thank you. I see my original post was not formatted correctly when I entered my code. What is the correct procedure to enter code and maintain indentation?

Comment: @Ali Highlight the all of the code you wish to indent. Then press the `{}` button in edit header, or use the shortcut keys `ctrl+k`.

Answer (score 0):

when you enter characters and the exception is thrown. the line `count = count + 1` still gets executed regardless. Because `count = count + 1` is not under `else:` That is why the count still gets incremented.
Also, realize that try-except statements don't repeat itself.